# WordPress get_post_meta Not Working in a Function

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a meta box on a custom post type for width.  Im trying to use `get_post_meta` to place some CSS in the head.  Everything is working but the meta value is not passing through.  Here is my function:

```
function mo_carousel_css(){
    global $post;
    $width = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mo_carousel_width', true );
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .jcarousel-container-horizontal{
        width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
```

I have checked the database and the meta key/value is being stored properly as `mo_carousel_width` and `500` respectively.  I thought `global $post;` would be the fix but no luck.

The value is retrieved fine in the metabox in the backend by accessing `$object` but that doesn't seem to work either.  This is code for the form that is creating the value:

```
    /* Display the post meta box. */
function mo_carousel_meta_box( $object, $box ) { ?>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'mo_carousel_nonce' ); ?>
    <p>
        <span>Carousel Size</span>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="mo-carousel-width" id="mo-carousel-width" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'mo_carousel_width', true ) ); ?>" size="10" />
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? Where did you use the function when you expected the output?

Comment: In a plugin.  I apologize.  I probably should have mentioned that.  And, im adding this function to the to wp_head through using `add_action('wp_head', 'mo_carousel_css');`.  The CSS is making it into the head, but the value is not.

Comment: Well... you do it the right way. I've seen similar code work. Try `global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->post->ID`. It accesses the same variable but it might be worth a try. I'm unsure if $post is set before the loop or not.

Comment: Thanks.  That doesnt work either.  The value is retrieved in the metabox just fine but by accessing `$object` which doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: try `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID);` and check the result. Dose it retrieves all values?

Comment: `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID);` returns `Array` and nothing else.

Comment: I think @DeminothBono meant `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mo_carousel_width', true );`

Comment: sorry I was confused with javascript :) `echo json_encode(get_post_meta($post->ID));` will display all of your meta. check whether there's 'mo_carousel_with' and it's value.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. Thats what I was doing in the code posted in the question which doesnt work.  @Deminoth Bono - `echo json_encode(get_post_meta($post->ID));` does not contain 'mo_carousel_width' and its value though it does contain other meta data from the page.  im at a loss here.

Comment: @WonderBred Do you actually save the value from the metabox somewhere? Just displaying a metabox does not automatically generate the code to save it.

Comment: See on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box the `myplugin_save_postdata` part of the example

Comment: Yes it is saved.  The problem is that this code is used with a shortcode and that shortcode is a custom post type.  So the shortcode is used to display that custom post type in a page.  The meta data is attached to the custom post. The shortcode contains the custom post id so I need to get it from there.  How can I access the shortcode atts in another function?  Thats the answer I need at this point.  I need something like "psuedo-code" `mo_carousel($atts)[id]` to use in the `mo_carousel_css()` function.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the page that is loaded - its ID - is not the same as the post of custom type for which you stored the meta value. If so, it makes sense that your approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this by studying the Shortcode API, and I think it should work but I haven't tried it.

```
function mo_carousel_css() {
    global $post;
    preg_match( '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/s', $post->post_content, $m); 
    if (is_array($m) && $m[2] == 'shortcode' ) { 
                $shortcode_args = shortcode_parse_atts( $m[3] );
        $width = get_post_meta( $shortcode_args['idatt'], 'mo_carousel_width', true );
        <style type="text/css">
            .jcarousel-container-horizontal{ width:<?php echo $width; ?>px; }
        </style>
    } 
}
```

Basically what it does is check if the shortcode is being used in the current post. If the shortcode is being used, retrieve the attributes from it and use the id attribute to get post meta data.

If your shortcode is `[displayCustomPost id=24]` then you would have to replace `shortcode` with `displayCustomPost` and `idatt` with `id`.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Thanks so much for digging into it for me.